# LINQ join in lambda with most recent date

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, ef-code-first

I'm trying to do a linq query on table 'Personen' and join table 'Leners'.
From table 'Leners' I would like the most recent item if available.

In SQL I would do that like this:

```
select p.*, l.* 
from dbo.Personen p
left outer join dbo.Leners l on l.LenerId = 
    (select top 1 LenerId 
     from dbo.Leners lt
     where lt.PersoonId = p.PersoonId 
     order by lt.Vanaf desc)
```

How can I do this with linq?
I would like to do this in a lambda expression because it depends on a selection.

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    var query = from p in db.Personen                        
                select p;

    if (someSelection != null)
    {
        query = ?
    }
}
```

These are the tables: (EF code first)

```
[Table("Personen")]
public class Persoon
{
    [Key]
    public int PersoonId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
}

[Table("Leners")]
public class Lener
{
    public int LenerId { get; set; }

    public int? PersoonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersoonId")]
    public virtual Persoon Persoon { get; set; }

    public DateTime Vanaf { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LINQ query should look like:

```
var query2 = from p in dbo.Personen
             let l = dbo.Leneren
                        .OrderByDescending(lt => lt.Vanaf)
                        .FirstOrDefault(lt => lt.PersoonId == p.PersoonId)
             select new { p, l }
```

However, you can't assign it back to your `query` variable!

```
var query = from p in db.Personen                        
            select p;
```

`query` is `IQueryable<Person>` because you're selecting `Person` items here. You can't reassign it to be `IQueryable<AnotherType>`.

Comment: Would it be possible if I added an extra property of type Lener to Person (not mapped to the database)?

Comment: How can I do that? (in lambda)

Comment: I tried your first query in linqpad. It works, but it is realy slow. (many sql statements instead of just one)

Comment: You shouldn't rely on linqpad. Try it in real application.

Comment: @Roeland You probable didn't link to your EF context in Linqpad. In linq to sql (default in linqpad) such queries can cause n+1 problems.